# Get File Name With PHP

Tags: php, file, directory

I'm using a php script to get all of the images from a folder and paginate them and everything works fine, however I'd like to use the actual photo name (filemname) as the alt tag but I'm finding it difficult to get the name. Any way that this can be done with the following code:

```
<?php
//The directory to your images folder, with trailing slash
$dir = "cms/gallery/photo/";

//Set the extensions you want to load, seperate by a comma.
$extensions = "jpeg,jpg,gif,png";

//Set the number of images you want to display per page
$imagesPerPage = 3;

//Set the $page variable
if(!isset($_GET['page'])){
    $page = 1;
}else{
    $page = $_GET['page'];
}

//Load all images into an array
$images = glob($dir."*.{".$extensions."}", GLOB_BRACE);

//Count the number of images
$totalImages = count($images);

//Get the total pages
$totalPages = ceil($totalImages / $imagesPerPage);

//Make sure the page you are on is not greater then the total pages available.
if($page > $totalPages){
    //Set the currnet page to the total pages.
    $page = $totalPages;
}

//Now find where to start the loading from
$from = ($page * $imagesPerPage) - $imagesPerPage;

//Now start looping
for($i = $from; $i < ($from + $imagesPerPage); $i++){
    //We need to make sure that its within the range of totalImages.
    if($i < $totalImages){
        //Now we can display the image!
        echo "

            <div class='galleryCellHolder'>
                <div class='galleryCell'>
                    <a class='fancybox' rel='group' href='{$images[$i]}'><img class='galleryPhoto' src='{$images[$i]}' alt='I NEED THIS TO BE THE FILE NAME'></a>
                </div>
            </div>

        ";
    }
}

//Now to display the page numbers!
for($p = 1; $p <= $totalPages; $p++){
    if($p == $page){
        $tmp_pages[] = "<strong class='pagination'>{$p}</strong>";
    }else{
        $tmp_pages[] = "<a class='pagination' href='?page={$p}'>{$p}</a>";
    }
}
?>
```

Comment: does my answer do what you want?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

use `basename()`.

```
$filename = explode('.', basename($images[$i]));
echo "
    <div class='galleryCellHolder'>
        <div class='galleryCell'>
            <a class='fancybox' rel='group' href='{$images[$i]}'><img class='galleryPhoto' src='{$images[$i]}' alt='" . $filename[0] . "'></a>
        </div>
    </div>    
";
```

Comment: It does but I was hoping to show just the title without the folder path & extension

Comment: This is now giving me: `Parse error: syntax error, unexpected '[', expecting ',' or ';' in C:\AppServ\www\---.com\photo-gallery.php on line 95`

Comment: Well that gets rid of the error but nothing shows up in the alt tag

Comment: @user3177012 if you're using a version of PHP lower than `5.2`, `$pathinfo["filename"]` wont work. Instead of that, use the edited version of my answer (I'll edit it right now)

Comment: Thanks, that works now! It's still showing the .jpg extension but I guess I can live with that - I'm uisng PHP Version 5.2.6

Comment: @user3177012 woops, the `,` in the explode should be a `.`. See my edit, now `.jpg` will be removed

Comment: Just out of curiosity, would you happen to know how to acheive the same thing by using a photo's EXIF name instead of the file name?

Comment: Thanks, I'm going to look into that

Answer (score 0):

Do it inside Your loop:

```
var_dump(basename($totalImages[$i]));
```

Or You can also check:

```
var_dump(pathinfo($totalImages[$i]));
```

There will be also basename, with dirname, extension etc.

Comment: Thanks but I'm still unsure of exactly where to put it in my script!

Comment: `$totalImages` is type `int`, not an `array`. The array containing the images is `$images`